How do I connect two optocouplers to my TDK-Lambda DRB240-24-1 AC-DC power supply?
I'm beginning to learn electrical system design, and I have an AC-DC power supply that outputs 24V DC. I will also be using an optocoupler (5V DC to 24V DC for my digital outputs) and another optocoupler (24V DC to 5V DC for digital outputs). How can two components be connected to my DRB240-24-1 power supply from TDK-Lambda?
In the applications sheet it says that terminals 8 and 9 are for optocoupler; from what I understand, only one optocoupler connects to those terminals. I have no idea how to go about it.
Here are the two optocouplers and working with and the power supply:
DRB240-24-1
5V DC to 24V DC optocoupler
24V DC to 5V DC optocoupler

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The supply's manual says it has a "DC OK" output which is active when output voltage is more than 80% of rated voltage. I assume this is to inform other systems that the supply is working properly, to detect faults, etc. This DC OK output uses an optocoupler for isolation, the opto is already inside the supply, and only its output is available on the connector. This output is not meant to power optocouplers that you will use to do other things. It's not clear what you want to do...

It would be helpful if you added a system block diagram, showing your supply, loads, control, and the voltage domains for each.  Also, a system description of your inputs and outputs and the isolation requirements.  Otherwise, we're just guessing at what you might be asking.

The manual says..."

DC OK
In normal operation the DC OK (optocoupler) is closed
when the output voltage is greater than 80% of nominal
output voltage. When the output is less than 80% of
nominal output voltage the optocoupler is open. "

This means the so-called optocoupler port is just a closed switch when DC is "OK" between pins 9 & 8.
That means you need to provide V+ a current limiting R and IR diode drop of ~1V to 1.2V with the cathode - lead to pin 9 and pin 8 to the V- of your external system supply.
I am assuming you have some reason for wanting this indicator to be isolated.
Swapping voltages requires different values with lower output current than input to guarantee your opto CTR is adequate.  CTR is like Beta in a transistor but with optical coupling losses.


I need to isolate my digital inputs and outputs from power supply. By using a USB-6421 multifunction I/O DAQ, I want to send digital outputs of 5 volts to control the 24VDC of the optocoupler and vice versa. 24VDC to 5VDC for digital inputs. The optocoupler components listed will be mounted in a DIN rail likewise the USB I/O. What confuses me is: How am I supposed to go about connecting these components together? do i need any extra external components like a fuse?

Well, like I mention the purpose is to control my digital inputs and outputs.

OK now define the specs for voltage, current , I/O speed and do not exceed the CTR minimum needed to work.
